# EHCache SizeOf warning

Tags: hibernate, ehcache, sizeof

I am using EHCache version 2.6.9 with Hibernate 4. I am seeing following warning in the logs:

net.sf.ehcache.pool.SizeOf.ObjectGraphWalker checkMaxDepth the configured limit of 1000 object references was reached while attempting to calculate the size of object graph....

I didn't set any limit to 1000. However after seeing this warning I defined sizeOfPolicy to 10000. However I still see the warning.

net.sf.ehcache.pool.SizeOf **deepsize** of the configured limit of 1000 object references was reached while attempting to calculate

1. Please suggest the possible solution?
2. What is the impact if I do not fix this warning?
3. Should I ignore these warning by putting @Ignoresizeof annotation on model objects? If yes, what is the impact?

Answer (score 1):

Answers to your questions:

1. The deepSize indicates that your are caching quite a large object graph - more than 10,000 *different* objects.
2. Cache size computation will be off, in the worst you would get out of memory before the cache starts evicting.
3. You can do that, but again, unless these are shared objects that should not be counted, doing so will mess up size computation.

Answer (score 1):

The magic number "***1000***" is the default depth that ehCache traverses before it logs a warning message and then continues to size the object graph. (They seem to have introduced this since ehCache version 2.5.0). See this link below:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/2.6.2/net/sf/ehcache/config/SizeOfPolicyConfiguration.java/

This default behaviour can however be changed using proper configuration directives. For the version that you mentioned, check the section '***Configuration for Limiting the Traversed Object Graph***' from the official doc below:

http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/ehcache-2.6.x-documentation.pdf

And I see @Louis answered all your questions in order. You may have to run some tests (may be load/perf tests) to see how far you want to control the depth of traversal to tune it based on your application behaviour and needs.

Answer (score 0):

No one addressed the issue of Hibernate in your question.

The problem that you are seeing is quite likely because the SizeOf component is traversing parts of Hibernate infrastructure such as session.

This is addressed by FilterConfigurators in sizeof.  I've forked the ehcache-sizeof-hibernate repository that targets Hibernate 4 and fixed it to work for Hibernate 5 [here](https://github.com/eccosolutions/ehcache-sizeofengine-hibernate/releases/tag/hib5-ehcache)